# Find first longest word in a string, excluding symbols

Tags: javascript

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var checkedLetters = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < str[j].length; j++) {
            if (j == /[^a-zA-Z]/) {
                checkedLetters += j;
            }
        if (longest < checkedLetters.length) {
            longest = checkedLetters.length;
            word = checkedLetters;
           }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my use of regex? When I call longestWord("Hello, I am here") I want it to return "Hello" (without the comma), but it returns null.

Comment: What if there are 2+ longest words?

Comment: Then I would want it to return the first longest word it comes across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistake in your code:

```
for (var j = 0; j < str[j].length; j++) {
```

should be

```
 for (var j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
```

And

```
if (j == /[^a-zA-Z]/) {
```

Should be:

```
if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i][j])) {
```

Your final code should be:

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var checkedLetters = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
            if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i][j])) {
                checkedLetters += str[i][j];
            }
        }
        if (longest < checkedLetters.length) {
            longest = checkedLetters.length;
            word = checkedLetters;
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CRLYw/)

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. It's also the first time I've come across .test.

Answer (score 5):

Just wrote this little snippet, might help you out:

```
function longestWord(string){
    return string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)
               .reduce(function(a,b){
                    return a.length>=b.length?a:b;
               })
}
```

`/[a-zA-Z]+/g` matches all words in the string, and returns an array of them. Your test string above (`"Hello, I am here"`) will become `["Hello","I","am","here"]` when this RegEx is run on it.

Once I have this array, it is simply a matter of looping through it to find the longest word. I accomplished this by using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: +1, but in accordance with what the OP specified in his comments, you should either use `reduceRight` or change your `>` to `>=`. An explanation wouldn't help either.

Comment: @Nile you mean, "wouldn't be bad, either", right? An explanation _would_ help

Comment: @JanDvorak Oops. Yeah, an explanation *would help. Thanks :)

Comment: also, `/\w+/` should be changed to `/[a-zA-Z]+/` to better match OP's requirements.

Comment: what if an empty string is passed to this function? how about  (string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)||[]) ?

Answer (score 1):

The big (non-typo) problem with how you’re using regular expressions is that the method is `.test`; `==` will test whether the string is equal to the string representation of the regular expression.

Just use `.match` and a little bit of `sort` magic!

```
function longestWord(string){
    var words = string.match(/\w+/g);
    words.sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; });
    // Firefox 22.0 promotion:
    // words.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

    return words[0];
}
```

Comment: I was just about to submit this same solution, decided not to. `sort` isn't a cheap operation. This ought to be O(n).

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Cheap is relative. If it’s performance-critical, sure, go with the raw loop.

Comment: Ad Firefox 22.0 promotion: any idea when Chrome's going to get this?

Comment: Javascript was the first to have first-class functions. Then they kinda exploded in popularity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Regex, you can just use .length to search for the longest string.

i.e.

```
function longestWord(string) {

    var str = string.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"").split(" ");
    longest = str[0].length;
    longestWord = str[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            longestWord= str[i];
           }
        }

return longestWord;
}
```

EDIT:  You do have to use some Regex...

Comment: This doesn’t ignore punctuation, though.

Comment: @minitech what if we split on `/[^a-z]+/i`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Sure, but that kind of takes out the “you don’t need to use regex” part :)

Comment: Fixed... but with Regex.  I have failed!

Comment: umm... that list of punctuation looks like a bad idea (for one, I think you forgot ``\``). Take my advice and use an inverted character class. And yeah, it no longer counts as a no-regex solution ;-)

Comment: Yeah, an inverted class would be much better. :)  Copy/Paste FTL