# Substring manipulation in Java - Find the longest word made from the other words

Tags: java, substring

I need to read the contents from a file and find the longest word that can be formed from the other words present in the file. The words in the file are space separated. For example :

Input from file :

```
This is example an anexample Thisisanexample Thisistheexample
```

Output :

```
Thisisanexample
```

**Note :** The longest word formed is `Thisisanexample` and not `Thisistheexample` because the word `the` is not contained as a separate word in the file.

Is this possible by using simple arrays? I have done the following :

```
try{
        File file = new File(args[0]);  //command line argument for file path
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line = null;
        //array for each word
        String[] words = new String[] {}; 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            words = line.split("\\s+"); //splitting the string with spaces
        }
        // array to store length of each word
        int[] wordLength = new int[words.length]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            wordLength[i] = words[i].length();
        }

        int currLength = 0; //store length of current word
        int maxLength = 0;  //store length of max word
        String maxWord = null;

        //checking each word with others at O(n*n) complexity
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            currLength = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length && j != i; j++){
                if (words[i].contains(words[j])){
                    currLength += wordLength[j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(currLength);
            if(currLength > maxLength){
                maxLength = currLength;
                maxWord = words[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxWord);
    }
```

But this does not work if there is a substring withing a substring. It will give wrong output for the following input :

```
This is example an anexample Thisisanexample Thisisanexample2
```

The output should be `Thisisanexample` but it gives `Thisisanexample2`.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387218/find-first-longest-word-in-a-string-excluding-symbols

Comment: @huanfeng, It's different from the one that you have linked.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , I have added the code written by me.

Comment: @titan7585 i see, it's an algorithm question, hope someone can help you:)

Comment: I have managed to solve it using some help from other Stack Overflow threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from other Stack Overflow threads, I have managed to do this by using arrays only.

Here is the solution :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LongestWord implements Comparator<String>{
    //compare function to be used for sorting the array according to word length
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() < s2.length())
           return 1;
    else if (s1.length() > s2.length())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new     FileInputStream(file)));
        String line = null;
        //array for each word
        String[] words = new String[] {}; 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            words = line.split("\\s+"); //splitting the string with spaces
        }

        //sort the array according to length of words in descending order
        Arrays.sort(words, new LongestWord());

        /* start with the longest word in the array and check if the other words are its substring.
         * If substring, then remove that part from the superstring.
         * Finally, if the superstring length is 0, then it is the longest word that can be formed.*/
        for (String superString: words) {
            String current = new String(superString); // to store a copy of the current superstring as we will remove parts of the actual superstring
            for (String subString: words) {
                if (!subString.equals(current) && superString.contains(subString)) { // superstring contains substring
                    superString = superString.replace(subString, "");  // remove the substring part from the superstring
                }
            }

            if (superString.length() == 0){
                System.out.println(current);
                break; // since the array is sorted, the first word that returns length 0  is the longest word formed
            }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fex){
        System.out.println("File not found");
        return;
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if (br != null){
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With just a few lines of code, you can use regex to find the candidate "combination" words, then simple logic to find the longest match:

```
String longest = "";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(this|is|an|example)+\\b").matcher(input);
while (m.find())
     if ( m.group().length() > longest.length())
        longest = m.group();
```

Apart from the code to read from the file and assigning a String to the variable `input`, that's all the code you need.